# A Scroll bar is getting displayed when i switch between tabs in angular material?

Tags: css, html, angular

```
<widget-shell [title]="data.title" (closeButtonClicked)="onCloseButtonClick($event)">
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabChange()">
    <mat-tab label="Data">
        <graph-bar *ngIf="graphSettings" [tabChanged]="tabChanged" [settings]="graphSettings.dataSeries"></graph-bar>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="SMS">
        <graph-bar *ngIf="graphSettings" [tabChanged]="tabChanged"  [settings]="graphSettings.smsSeries"></graph-bar>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Voice">
        <graph-bar *ngIf="graphSettings" [tabChanged]="tabChanged"  [settings]="graphSettings.voiceSeries"></graph-bar>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

> In the CSS:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-body-content {
      overflow: visible !important;
    }
```

> By using the above css solved the issue,but is there some other way
>   that we can achieve the same without using `!important`

Answer (score 10):

here is a better solution (tested on v-7):

```
<mat-tab-group [dynamicHeight]='true'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is!

You will need to set `overflow: visible;`, but this is the thing: you need to make sure your CSS is higher priority than the angular's styling. Please take a look here at the CSS priority:  http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/ and http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

So you can use the developer tools to inspect the styling of the component you want to override, then make a higher priority than that styling.

easy tips: copy and paste the order you find in the dev tools, then put your styling inside and make sure your file to override comes later than the angular material's css

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behaviour of mat tabs.Even i faced the same issue.I fixed this issue by placing the above code in the css file,

::ng-deep .mat-tab-body-content {
    overflow: visible !important
  }

Remember: Don't forget to add !important in css,if not it gets ignored and will never apply to your tab.